# Принцип работы с большими файлами

Tags: delphi

Каков принцип работы с большими файлами для достижения наибольшей производительности? Нужно будет добавлять, считывать и удалять данные из произвольного места файла. Считывать все в память и там обрабатывать или есть другие способы?

Comment: что за файл - текстовый, двоичный, какой-то свой формат с записями?

Comment: и сколько это "большой", и почему именно файловый формат выбран для хранения.

Comment: @slippyk, двоичный.

Comment: @teran, нужно сохранять информацию на диск и загружать с него, а также, обновлять. Размер в пределах 500mb.

Comment: почему не какая нибудь локальная СУБД?

Comment: Если требуется именно наибольшая производительность, то лучше копать в сторону [отображения файла в память](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C).

Comment: ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/889749/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

500 мегабайт для современных компьютеров плевое дело, для телефонов тоже посильная работа. Поэтому загружаем последовательно всю информацию в память, обабатываем и последовательно записываем (на HDD произвольный доступ очень медленный). В некоторых случаях, думаю, это будет не медленнее, чем попытка записывать только измененные данные.